# Determine number of digits bash

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, scripting, arguments

I have a date that is inputted into a bash script through 3 separate command line arguments.  The user could put in either 1 or 2 digits for the month and day and 4 digits for the year (eg. `2014 01 01` or `2014 1 1`).  But my script needs two digits to run.  I was thinking of using an if statement to handle this.  It would basically say "if the amount of digits in the month is less than 2 then put a leading zero in front of it". Though, I am unsure how to determine the amount of digits in bash. I am rather new to scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this using the `printf` command:

```
month=5
month2=`printf %02d $month`
```

The `%02d` format specifier formats `$month` as two decimal digits with a leading zero if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For any bash variable `$x` (including parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc.), `${#x}` is the length of `$x` in characters.